# AS400 to Oracle 10g via xml with Informatica Powercenter

Tags: oracle, etl, ibm-midrange, informatica-powercenter

Is the following workflow possible with Informatica Powercenter?

AS400 -> Xml(in memory) -> Oracle 10g stored procedure (pass xml as param)

Specifically, I need to take a result set eg. 100 rows. Convert those rows into a single xml document as a string in memory and then pass that as a parameter to an Oracle  stored procedure that is called *only once.* I understood that a workflow runs row-by-row and this kind of 'batching' is not possible.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't understand the question?

Comment: Oh I understand it, I just don't know the answer as it's been a few years since I worked in that environment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, this scenario should be possible.**

- You can connect to AS/400 sources with native Informatica connector(s), although this might require (expensive) licenses. Another option is to extract the data from AS/400 source into a text file, and use that as a normal file source.
- To convert multiple rows into one row, you would use an `Aggregator` transformation. You may need to create a dummy column (with same value for all rows) using an `Expression`, and use that column as the grouping key of the Aggregator, to squeeze the input into one single row. Row values would be concatenated together (separated by some special character) and then you would use another Expression to split and parse the data into as many ports (fields) as you need.
- Next, with an `XML Generator` transformation you can create the XML. This transformation can have multiple input ports (fields) and its result will be directed into a single output port.
- Finally, you would load the generated XML value into your Oracle target, possibly using a `Stored Procedure` transformation.